# Grouping and ordering using ActiveRecord Query interface

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have a model, `ConnectedUser`, which belongs to 2 other models `User` and `Station`.

It is a simple model with just those relationships and a boolean `active`.

The results of the query I'm aiming for would be only each most recent `ConnectedUser` record for each `User` (where the `Station` is a specific id).

For example, if my `ConnectedUser` table looked like this...

```
+----+---------+------------+--------+------------+
| id | user_id | station_id | active | created_at |
+----+---------+------------+--------+------------+
|  1 |       1 |          1 | true   | 20 June    |
|  2 |       1 |          1 | false  | 19 June    |
|  3 |       1 |          2 | false  | 20 June    |
|  4 |       2 |          1 | false  | 18 June    |
|  5 |       2 |          1 | false  | 21 June    |
+----+---------+------------+--------+------------+
```

And the station was the one with id 1 then I'd like the query to return...

```
[
<ConnectedUser id: 1, user_id: 1, station_id: 1, active: true, created_at: "2019-06-20">,
<ConnectedUser id: 5, user_id: 2, station_id: 1, active: false, created_at: "2019-06-21">
]
```

To achieve this I've been trying to use `group` to and `order`

```
ConnectedUser.where(station: station).select(:user_id).group(:user_id).order(:created_at)
```

but have kept getting errors like this:

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column
>   "connected_users.created_at" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be
>   used in an aggregate function)

I am unable to get the specific `ConnectedUser` id, so feel like I'm missing some important understanding how to work with `group` and aggregate the results.

Is this possible in one ActiveRecord query?

Many thanks.

Comment: Apologies, it should not change, I have edited to fix that.

Answer (score 1):

In Postgres, if you want the most recent version for each user/station, I would recommend `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (station_id, user_id) cu.*
from ConnectedUser cu
order by station_id, user_id, created_at desc;
```

Comment: Thanks, I'd like to user ActiveRecord query if possible so I can pass in the `station` via parameters.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `DISTINCT ON` instead of `GROUP`. Here is how you can do it in Rails:

```
ConnectedUser.select("DISTINCT ON (station_id, user_id) *")
             .where(station_id: params[:station_id])
             .order(created_at: :desc)
```

Of course with `params[:station_id]` is what you want to filter

Comment: Thanks, trying that `ConnectedUser.select("DISTINCT ON (station_id, user_id)").where(station: station).order(created_at: :desc)` gives this error for me though... `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "FROM")
LINE 1: SELECT DISTINCT ON (station_id, user_id) FROM "connected_use...`

Comment: Yeah, it seems I forgot character * in the select statement. Please see my updated answer and see if it works now

Answer (score 0):

Probaly, this would solve it

`ConnectedUser.where(active: true).order(user_id: :desc).uniq(&:user_id)`

`order` is used to sort the `user_id` field in `DESC`

on this solution, i am using `uniq`, which is a array solution, and will select just the most recent `user_id`

edit:

I was wrong, uniq didnt work as expected, but testing here, i discover that:

`ConnectedUser.where(active: true).order(created_at: :desc).group(:user_id)`

seems much like yours, but, when you use select, it does select just the field user_id, so, you can't order by `created_at`

Should work

Comment: Thanks, using `uniq` seems interesting but I think `uniq` has been deprecated now in favour of `distinct`. When trying it it doesn't seem to return the most recent records either—but ordering by created_at instead didn't seem to help.

Comment: Hi, with the edited version I'm now getting the familiar error again which I've been trying to resolve: `(PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "connected_users.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function)` thanks for trying.

Comment: @Chris, and if you try to put `id` inside the group, like `group(:id, :user_id)` ?

Comment: Yeh, I've tried this approach and variations of it, without any luck. Thanks again.